# How to script with systemd-cgtop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd

The manpage for [systemd-cgtop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/systemd-cgtop.1.html) says that if there is no attached tty it will do one iteration and then print it out, saying that this would be useful in scripts.

However when I try to do this from a script, it does not work as advertised:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(systemd-cgtop|grep ezdose)
echo $line
```

Running the script as so:

```
$ bash test.sh
(hangs with no output)
```

How do you work this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-cgtop -n1   will do 1 iteration

To find if you are attached to a tty put a line in your script:  tty

```
#!/bin/sh
#  How to check what tty you are on.
echo -ne "Connected TTY: "`tty`

line=$(systemd-cgtop -n1|grep ezdose)
echo $line
```

Comment: Damn, I must be running an old version, no `-n` option.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the [NEWS](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS):

> CHANGES WITH 201:
>
> systemd-cgtop has also been updated to be 'pipeable' for processing with further shell tools.

So, you can run `systemd-cgtop | grep ...` since `v201`.

> CHANGES WITH 188:
>
> cgtop gained a new -n switch (similar to top), to configure the maximum number of iterations to run for. It also gained -b, to run in batch mode (accepting no input).

You can run `systemd-cgtop -n1 -b | grep ...` . But `systemd-cgtop` prints `Path Tasks %CPU Memory Input/s Output/s` as the first line (until `v201`).

Also:

> CHANGES WITH 221:
>
> The systemd-cgtop tool learnt a new --raw switch to generate "raw" (machine parsable) output.

With the `--raw` option you get sizes in bytes: i.e. `92213248` instead of `87.9M`

Answer (score 1):

In my case `systemd-cgtop -n1 -b | grep ...` didn't return the cpu usage, so I added one more iteration like `systemd-cgtop -n2 -b | grep ...` and it worked.